# Bootstrap 5 Collapsing Navbar won't show when pressing toggler

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a collapsing navbar but it just doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.

I've got this collapse toggler and it should target #navbar1 but when shrinking the page the Navbar collapses the .navbar-toggler-icon shows up but when clicking the toggler it just won't pop up again. When inspecting the CSS there is a selector .collapse:not(.show) that applies a display:none; but when i add that class .show it is always shown and does not hide by pressing the toggler..

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: i have bootstrap.min.js included

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
   <div class="container-lg">
     <ul class="navbar-brand navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Teamserver.at</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar1" aria-controls="navbar1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
         <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">XMPP/Jabber</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
               <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Über Teamserver</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Webinterface</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Einstellungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Software</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-light">Sign in</button></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button></a>
          </li>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have two separate menus (one for nav links and one for signing in or up), create two `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menu" id="navbar1">` with unique IDs and a common class. The toggle button’s `data-bs-target` gets set to the class, `.navbar-menu` and the `aria-controls` gets the two IDs, `navbar1 navbar2`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
<div class="container-lg">
    <ul class="navbar-brand navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Teamserver.at</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-menu" aria-controls="navbar1 navbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menu" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">XMPP/Jabber</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Über Teamserver</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Webinterface</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Einstellungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Software</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menu ml-auto" id="navbar2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-light">Sign in</button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button></a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

You had a class on the second navbar, `navbar-right`, but that’s not a standard Bootstrap class.

### Update

Added a version that keeps the sign-in and sign-up buttons in the navbar all the time.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container-lg">
        <ul class="navbar-brand navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Teamserver.at</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-1 order-lg-0" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">XMPP/Jabber</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Über Teamserver</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Webinterface</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Einstellungen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Software</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-right d-flex flex-nowrap">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-3">Sign in</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary me-3">Sign up</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar1" aria-controls="navbar1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```